# Align text in labels and text boxes?

Tags: vba, excel

Even if text box controls and label control are aligned, the text in them does not appear in the same vertical position.

Is there any good practice for how to align text in labels and text boxes in VBA userforms?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the `.Top` and `.Font` and `.FontSize` of both the controls are same, there will still be some difference because the TextBox has a border and the Label doesn't.

[image]

You will have to either

1. Manually move the Label up and down or
2. Remove the border of the Textbox.

[image]

Here is a side by side comparison

[image]

**Edit**: Oh BTW, if you choose the first option, i.e, moving the Label up and down, then here is a neat trick which may help you. Add a command button and reduce it's height so it looks like a thin line. Use that as a scale to align the controls and then in the end simply delete the command button.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your great and very helpful answer. I removed the border.

Answer (score 3):

After many years this question was still relevant to me. Here's my solution:

I found that this is easily solved by looping over every control when initializing the form and adjusting the height for each label by 2. All you need to do is give all labels that you want to move a similar naming convention which you can use in the If statement, "lbl_" in my case.

```
For Each contr In Me.Controls

If contr.Name Like "lbl_*" Then
    
    contr.top = contr.top + 2
    
End If
Next
```